# If $\frac{f'}{f}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=\frac{g'}{g}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$ $\forall n$

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f,g\in H(\mathbb{D})$, and there are no zeroes in $\mathbb{D}$. If $\frac{f'}{f}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=\frac{g'}{g}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$ $\forall n$, then $f=kg$ for some $k\in \mathbb{C}$.

I don't see what theorem should I use to prove it. Any hints to solve this problem?

Comment: $f'/f$ should, in general, invoke the idea of $\log(f)$ shortly after. Also the set $\{1/n\}$ accumulates in $\mathbb{D}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\phi(z) = {g(z) \over f(z)}$ and note that
$\phi'({1 \over n}) = 0$ hence $ \phi' = 0$ and so $\phi$ is a constant. Hence
$g(z) = \phi(0) f(z)$.

Comment: But why if $\phi'(1/n)=0$ can you conclude that $\phi '$ is always zero?

Comment: I can't. I concluded that $\phi$ is a constant.

Comment: Are you asking how I concluded that $\phi'$ is always zero?

Comment: Yes, it was a typo. I already edited the comment. Does it follow from the identity theorem?

Comment: If the zeros of an analytic function has an accumulation point inside a connected domain ($0$ in this instance) then the function is identically zero on that connected domain. Is that what you mean by the identity theorem?